# Blocos um ao lado do outro em cima e embaixo

Tags: css

Olá, venho adiando essa dúvida e deixando de lado [...]
Busco solução simples para deixar blocos de tabelas lado a lado.
Nesse exemplo os blocos iniciam na margem de baixo pra cima com alinhamento do bloco que contém 'height' maior. Quero que inicie de cima de pra baixo, e quando houver um bloco com 'height' maior não desvele, sendo alinhado ao lado ou embaixo num espaço de 3px.

```
<style>
    body{
        background:black;
    }
</style>

<h2>Titulo</h2>
<ul class="galeria">
    <li><div style="position:relative;width:100px; height:100px; background:yellow;"</div></li>
    <li><div style="position:relative;width:100px; height:320px; background:yellow;"</div></li>
    <li><div style="position:relative;width:100px; height:100px; background:yellow;"</div></li>
    <li><div style="position:relative;width:100px; height:100px; background:yellow;"</div></li>
    <li><div style="position:relative;width:100px; height:100px; background:yellow;"</div></li>
</ul>


<style>
.galeria {
    padding-right: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}

.galeria li {
    padding-left: 0.1em;
    padding-right: 0.1em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
}
</style>
```

• Uma dica já serve ;)

Answer (score 1):

O elemento `<li>` da forma que vc formatou com `display:inline-block` pode receber a propriedade `vertical-align`, então basta colocar `vertical-align:top` que ele vai alinhar ao topo e não a base do irmão mais alto. Para manter o espaço entre o elemento de cima e da linha de baixo vc pode usar um `padding-top` como no código abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
body {
    background: black;
}

.galeria {
    padding-right: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}

.galeria li {
    padding-left: 0.1em;
    padding-right: 0.1em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
    vertical-align: top;
padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Entendi! Fico envergonhado de minhas perguntas bestas. Obrigado pelo exemplo em resposta, quando os blocos saem da sequência de uma linha passando para outra fica desnivelado. Tentei outras formas usando float e clear mas não consegui. Tem alguma artimanha que possa compartilhar?
Quando digo desnivelado digo não próximo um do outro num espaço digamos de 3px.

Comment: @Jonathan tem formas mais simples para tratar isso com display:flex que eh o que eu indico, ou no seu caso basta colocar um padding-top como falei nos itens que forem ficar na segunda linha de baixo depois dos 4 primeiros. Se vc tiver alguma dúvida em como fazer esse exemplo com flex basta abrir outra pergunta pedindo ajuda com isso. Se essa resposta resolveu o problema considere marca-la como aceita nesse ícone ao lados das setinhas da resposta ✔